# how to use rootBundle to load config in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using rootBundle to load config in flutter(2.5.x), this is my code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final jsonStr = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/static/emoji-flags.json", cache: false);
}
```

and I already config the path in `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/translations/
    - assets/static/
```

but this code running error like this:

```
E/flutter (14207): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (14207): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:222:39)
E/flutter (14207): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:68:33)
E/flutter (14207): #2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:18)
E/flutter (14207): #3      main (package:flutter_learn/main.dart:10:36)
E/flutter (14207): #4      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:25)
E/flutter (14207): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter (14207): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (14207): #7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
E/flutter (14207): #8      runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
E/flutter (14207): #9      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:141:5)
E/flutter (14207): #10     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
E/flutter (14207): #11     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter (14207):
```

what should I do to load this config success? Am I  missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is my environment reader, I map my json file to the data model.

```
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

  static Future<void> initializeApp(String? env) async {
    env = env ?? "development";
    final configString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/env.json');
    final jsonMap = json.decode(configString);
    _config = ConfigModel.fromMap(jsonMap[env]);
  }
```